# Cut string in android

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i have a string:

```
String a = "234 - 456";
```

I want cut this string and assign the first number in int firstnumber and second number a int secondnumber.

is possible?
P.S 123 and 456 are dinamyc number!

The numbers are separated with a " - "
Thank you

Comment: Who down votes without leaving a comment as to why so the user may benefit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `str.split();` Example:

```
String a = "234 - 456";
String[] strings = a.split(" - ");
// Then you can parse them
// You may want to do a check here to see if the user entered real numbers or not
// This is only needed for user input, if the numbers are hard coded you don't need this, although it doesn't hurt to have it
int firstNumber = 0; // Assign them before hand so you can use them after the try catch
int secondNumber = 0;
try {
    firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]); // firstNumber becomes 234
    secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]); // secondNumber becomes 456
} catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    System.out.println("Please enter real numbers!");
}
```

Comment: thank you! if i have this string with 3 numbers?? a = "234 - 456 - 678"; ? i want assing firstnumber secondnumber and thirdnumber?!?!

Comment: Then you it is just a matter of adding a new variable: `int thirdNumber = Integer.parseInt(strings[2]);`

Answer (score 2):

You will want to put validation code in for each step. You want to know the value you have is good.

```
if(a!=null &&a.Contains(" - ")) {
     String[] separated = CurrentString.split(" - ");
}


separated[0]; // This will contain the first number
separated[1]; //  This will contain the second number
```

Edit

```
int valueOne= 0; 
int valueTwo= 0;
try {
    valueOne = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]); // firstNumber becomes 234
    valueTwo = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]); // secondNumber becomes 456
} catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    System.out.println("Please enter real numbers!");
}
```

Comment: NO. separated[0] contains "234 " and separated[1] contains " 456". Mind the spaces!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thanks, I assumed you user could figure that out and use a trim function or add the spaces to the split. Either way answer was updated.

Comment: Don't give anything for assumed. Newbies trying your code (before updating), it doesn't work and possibly downvote... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below should work, use split() function:

```
String[] strArray = input.split(" - ");
int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
}

int intA = intArray[0];
int intB = intArray[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] parts = a.split(" - ");
int[] numb = new int[parts.length];
for(int n = 0; n < parts.length; n++) {
   numb[n] = Integer.parseInt(parts[n]);
}
firstnumber = numb[0];
secondnumber = numb[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

To separate your string you should use a `StringTokenIzer` and make with a "-" as a delimiter and make sure to trim the token you got.

```
String a = "234 - 456";

        int number_1 = 0, number_2 = 0;

        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(a, "-");

        if(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){


            number_1 =  Integer.valueOf(stringTokenizer.nextToken().trim()).intValue();
            number_2 =  Integer.valueOf(stringTokenizer.nextToken().trim()).intValue();

        }
```